# How to copy a Parse.File(image)

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I am use express + parse server, I want to design a function in server side node.js to copy the image. I can query and get the existing Parse File, but how to copy and save a new one ?

```
    var imageQuery = new Parse.Query("ProductImage");
    imageQuery.equalTo("products", product);
    imageQuery.find({
        success: function(productImages) {

            if (productImages.length > 0) {
                var image = productImages[0].get("imgoneS");
                for (var key in image) {
                    console.log(key + ": " + image[key]);
                }
                //console.log key only _url and _name
                //how to copy a new image and save?

            }


        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("product_stat_copyproduct ProductImage query error: " + error);

        }
    })
```

Comment: Please show your attempts and what code you have already tried?

Comment: I have update and note my existing code.

Comment: You want to copy the url or all data inside the url ?

Comment: I want to copy parse file, as a new one. Not url only

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do, is to get the data from the file, and initialize a new file with that data. Something like this (**not tested**) should work in Cloud Code. `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` is available on Cloud Code only, if you're doing this in a client side JS, use request or other networking library:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: originalFile.url()}).then(function(response) {
     // The file contents are in response.buffer.
    var copiedFile = new Parse.File("MyCopy.someExtension", response.buffer);
    return copiedFile.save();
}.then(function() {
    //copied file was saved!
});
```